# Prove that $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}-\left \{ 1 \right \}$ given by $f(x) = x+1$ is $1$-$1$ and onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}-\{1\}$ given by $f(x) = x+1$ is $1$-$1$ and onto.

Proof:
($1$-$1$) Suppose $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$ for $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x_{1} + 1 = x_{2} + 1 \Rightarrow x_{1} = x_{2}$.

(onto) Let $y\in \mathbb{N} - \left \{ 1 \right \}$, and let $x = y - 1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f(x) = y - 1 + 1 = y$. $\square$

---

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Yes. Both the proofs are valid.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Another way would be to define $\phi: \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb{N} $ by $\phi(x) = x-1$. Then note that $\phi(f(x)) = x, f(\phi(x)) = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. You have provided a valid way to prove that $f$ is *bijective*, i.e. *one-to-one* and *onto*.

Comment: In other words, yes.

Comment: Who voted to delete this answer and why?

Comment: Not entirely clear. When you use this tone (with italics as well) it makes it sound like you are correcting the OP on something.